# MDX crossjoin only where members are equal

Tags: ssas, mdx

Is it possible to cross join and return only where two members are equal? For example the following query against the Adventure Works in SSAS 2012

```
select [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount] on 0
,topcount(([Ship Date].[Date].Children,[Delivery Date].[Date].Children),5) on 1
from [Adventure Works]
```

would return the following values

```
                     Reseller Sales Amount
January 1, 2005 January 1, 2005 (null)
January 1, 2005 January 2, 2005 (null)
January 1, 2005 January 3, 2005 (null)
January 1, 2005 January 4, 2005 (null)
January 1, 2005 January 5, 2005 (null)
```

What I would like as the result is the following

```
                     Reseller Sales Amount
January 1, 2005 January 1, 2005 (null)
January 2, 2005 January 2, 2005 (null)
January 3, 2005 January 3, 2005 (null)
January 4, 2005 January 4, 2005 (null)
January 5, 2005 January 5, 2005 (null)
```

Can I get a result such as the following using an MDX query with or without using a crossjoin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. Basically I create a Boolean style calculated member, and then include that member in the TOPCOUNT function.

I hope it helps.

Ash

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MatchingDates] AS
IIF([Ship Date].[Date].MEMBERVALUE = [Delivery Date].[Date].MEMBERVALUE,1,0)
SELECT
[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount] ON 0
,   TOPCOUNT({[Ship Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS * [Delivery Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS},5,[Measures].[MatchingDates]) ON 1
FROM
[Adventure Works]
```

Comment: `NULL` instead of 0 is better as the second arg of `IIF`